# Shopping list name with apostrophe is not getting deleted or opened

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

i have one cart page, in that page i have created a sample shopping list such as EX:- sample1 ,once i created if i wish i can delete the cart 
but when im trying to create another shopping list as EX:- sample2' ..with apostrophe the item is not deleting 
could any one suggest me what changes i have to do

code is as below for deleting

```
<c:forEach var="wishList" items="${wlist}">
 <tr class=" ">
              <td><a href="javascript:createwishlist('${wishList.name}')" >${wishList.name}</a> </td>
              <td> <fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MM/yy" 
            value="${wishList.lastmodifieddate}" /></td>
              <td class="centred"><a href="javascript:deletewishlist('${wishList.name}','${removewishlistUrl}')"><spring:theme code="delete.table.shoppinglist"/></a></td>
            </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

in first example its taking 'sample1'
in second one its taking 'sample2'' like this that's why its not deleting could you plz suggest me how to modify it

```
<div class="shoplist">
            <c:if test="${not empty wlist}">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tableshoplist">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="header">
                            <td width="75%"><spring:theme
                                    code="name.table.shoppinglist" /></td>
                            <td width="15%"><spring:theme code="date.table.shoppinglist" /></td>
                            <td width="10%" align="center"><spring:theme
                                    code="delete.table.shoppinglist" /></td>
                        </tr>

                        <c:forEach var="wishList" items="${wlist}">
                            <tr class=" ">
                                <td><a href="javascript:createwishlist('${wishList.name}')">${wishList.name}</a>
                                </td>
                                <td><fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MM/yy"
                                        value="${wishList.lastmodifieddate}" /></td>
                                <td class="centred"><a
                                    href="javascript:deletewishlist('${wishList.name}','${removewishlistUrl}')">
                                        <spring:theme code="delete.table.shoppinglist" />
                                </a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </c:if>
        </div>
```

-------------------------------JavaScript function

```
function deletewishlist(id, url) {
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete shopping list");
    if (r == true) {
        $("#existname").val(id);
        $("#wishlistform").attr("action", url);
        $("#wishlistform").submit();
    } else {
        txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get?Please add in deletion process fucntion

Comment: actually if i created any item with single quote,it's not clickable and not delete ..

Comment: So I suppose u r using a JS function for deletion,and it seems it must throwing some errors in browser console due to scritpting errors because of special character

Comment: just option is disable, it's not showing any error on console

Comment: Plz add in the js function code to the question

Comment: i added below its the code .the code is written in jsp

Comment: deletewishlist() function in javascript which actually does the deleting in page plz!

Comment: yeah i added the js function plz have look on it

Comment: Either avoid using apostrophe in element id or escape it using \ character like sample2\'

Comment: yeah i tried to escape it but it's not allowing me to do